# Define colors depending on difference to previous value - points and lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to create a plot which returns me the colours of each point conditionated by the previous one. In other words, if the y value of x is greater than in x-1, then it should show up in green whereas if it were smaller it should appear in red.

Is there an easy way to do it with ggplot2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using the sign of the difference, assuming data is sorted on `x`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = runif(20, min = 0, max = 2))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(c(0, sign(diff(y)))))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "grey", "green"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT:

To do this for lines, it is often best to reparametrize data to `geom_segment()`s, since I don't think `geom_line()` handles multiple colours per line very well. Example below of converting the `economics` data to segments.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- economics[, c("date", "unemploy")]
df$date_end <- c(tail(df$date, -1), NA)
df$unemploy_end <- c(tail(df$unemploy, -1), NA)
df <- head(df, -1)

ggplot(df, aes(date, unemploy,
               xend = date_end,
               yend = unemploy_end)) +
  geom_segment(aes(colour = unemploy  > unemploy_end))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: How should I do to do the same with ```geom_line``` so it reflects positive or negative trends?

Comment: See the edit, I don't think it extends to `geom_line()` as easily.

Comment: very pretty graph, and nice usage of geom_segment. (although the colors seem the wrong way round)

Comment: One last question: I'm trying to rename the labels on the legend at the right side on the plot, but unsuccessfully. How does it work?

Comment: You can use `scale_colour_*(name = "My legend title", labels = c("upward", "downward"))` or something of the sort. Where `*` is a discrete scale, such as `manual` or plain `discrete`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = runif(20, min = 0, max = 2))

v <- (unlist(lapply(1:20, function(i) ifelse(df$y[i] > df$y[i-1], "green", "red"))))
# add your condition on first element (e.g "blue")
v <- c("blue", v)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y), color = v)
```